# How do I render pdf in GRAILS 4?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to render pdf in GRAILS 4.4 but it seems all of the rendering plugins fail to work? Is there any way I could render pdf from template or normal view in GRAILS 4 as it's done in Grails 3?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.